# Compare RegExp-string with special characters in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, match

it is needed to compare $string1 to certain string-template in PowerShell

```
PS C:\ $string1 = '\\<a href="main\\.php\\?act=forum\\&hdl=read_\\&id=(\d+)\\&pid=313" class="small_name2"\\>Learn the powershell tool\\</a\\>'
PS C:\ $string1 -match '<a href="main.php?act=forum&hdl=read_&id=83523&pid=313" class="small_name2">Learn the powershell tool</a>'
False
```

What is wrong in templates and maybe string above?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-match` operator is not commutative, so you can't switch the operands. First operand must be the string you want to match against a regular expression, second operand must be the regular expression. Also, the double backslashes in your regular expression evaluate to literal backslashes instead of escaping special characters.

Change this:

```
$string1 = '\\<a href="main\\.php\\?act=forum\\&hdl=read_\\&id=(\d+)\\&pid=313" class="small_name2"\\>Learn the powershell tool\\</a\\>'
$string1 -match '<a href="main.php?act=forum&hdl=read_&id=83523&pid=313" class="small_name2">Learn the powershell tool</a>'
```

into this:

```
$string1 = '\<a href="main\.php\?act=forum\&hdl=read_\&id=(\d+)\&pid=313" class="small_name2"\>Learn the powershell tool\</a\>'
'<a href="main.php?act=forum&hdl=read_&id=83523&pid=313" class="small_name2">Learn the powershell tool</a>' -match $string1
```

Comment: Might want to mention `[RegEx]::Escape()`  :)

Comment: `[regex]::Escape()` would help, but since the expression contains a group `(\d+)` the substrings before and after it would have to be escaped separately, e.g. like this: `[regex]::Escape('<a h...&id=') + '(\d+)' + [regex]::Escape('&pid...</a>')`

Comment: Thank both you a lot.
I have a complex error. Main parts are: 1) incorrect order and 2) a mistake in RegExp synax.